# Пропадают компьютеры из сетевого окружения

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-7, windows-10, lan

В сети около 8 компьютеров под управлением Win7/10. 
Периодически один компьютер не видит один из других компьютеров в сетевом окружении. При прямом входе на другой компьютер (//PCname) все работает.

Искал информацию в google, знаю про master browser. Вопрос в том, как так настроить компьютеры, чтобы все работало (периодически некоторые компьютеры выключаются в зависимости от присутствия сотрудника в офисе).

Comment: Поставить в качестве master browser'а самбу на невыключающемся Orange Pi Zero?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в Диспетчере устройств настройку сетевой карты. Возможно там стоит режим энергосбережения. Отключите его. Ещё можно уменьшить один из параметров отвечающий за скорость доступа по сети. Сталкивался уже с таким. Только уже не помню какой.